# Other projections in Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, map-projections, mercator

I'm plotting data using lat/lons with Google Maps API.  However, some of my data is at high latitude, and it isn't plotted because Google Maps uses a Mercator projection which cuts off at 85 degrees.  Is there any way around this?

Here's my current map: http://erbweather.com/choosestation_GSOD_global.html

For Antarctica, I'm using a different map entirely: http://erbweather.com/choosestation_GSOD_Antarctica.html

Is there a way to have all data on one (good looking and responsive) map?

Answer (score 3):

I recently asked a similar question (which sadly got voted down): [Is it possible to use non Mercator projections in Mapbox, Google Maps or any other webmap API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417134/is-it-possible-to-use-non-mercator-projections-in-mapbox-google-maps-or-any-oth)

Google's Mercator projection cuts off at 85 degrees because things get extremely distorted after that point.

As far as I know there are limited options for non-Mercator projections in web map APIs. Here are the best I've found so far:

- Google [sort of](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ProjectionImplemention) supports other projections
- OpenLayers [supports](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj_Projection.html) other projections using [proj4](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js)
- This open [issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3184) on Mapbox might be worth following
- [Cesium](https://cesiumjs.org/demos/Geospatial/) supports globe/ flat views
- If you only need limited web map functionality then d3 could provide some options: e.g. [d3-geo-projection](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/)